# How do I exclude zero (0) values but include numbers with a zero in them, like 10, 20, 300 etc? In query

Tags: sql

Current formula as written by my predecessor:

```
Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type41","0","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Target Qty"})
```

I need a formula that will only blank out cells with JUST a zero, not a 10 or a 200 for example.

Not sure what to try

Comment: Formula? Is this excel or SQL?

Comment: Anyway, the normal way to handle this is to actually convert or treat the entire value as a number and compare to 0, rather than doing text manipulation.

Comment: If this is Power Query M (and not SQL), change Replacer.ReplaceText to Replacer.ReplaceValue.

Comment: How is this SQL? Not seeing any SQL syntax. Add tag(s) for relevant tools.